# Sending email with rich text and embedded image using Python

Tags: python, html, email, mime-types, mime

I am learning how to use Python for automating emails, and am facing issues in creating a "clean" email.

**Problem**: I have a Google doc which has a certain text, followed by an image, followed by some text. I wish to use this as the content of an email, which I wish to send using Python

**Approach**: Based on what I read on SO and blogs, I used MIMEMultipart and broke my original doc into 3 parts: [text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gHKwJuuzK0JQPtj95bERoEsvWd-1Jp_7eWdhZ8aT1rc/edit?usp=sharing), [image](https://i.morioh.com/2020/04/28/356ff17f96b9.jpg), [text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zyZyELux_DzzmTJYSgWBbFl-1DjXKHQ1ay_-c4gOycQ/edit?usp=sharing) and I downloaded the html versions for both the text files. Thereafter, I used the following code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

from string import Template

me = "myemail@gmail.com"
you = "youremail@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
msg['Subject'] = 'This is a test'

html1 = open('test_doc_part1.html')
part1 = MIMEText(html1.read(), 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
html1.close()

image_text = MIMEText('<img src="cid:image1">', 'html')
msg.attach(image_text)
fp = open('test_image.jpg', 'rb')
image = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>') # Define the image's ID as referenced in the HTML body above
msg.attach(image)

html2 = open('test_doc_part2.html')
part2 = MIMEText(html2.read(), 'html')
msg.attach(part2)
html2.close()


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(me, "password")

text = msg.as_string()
# Do text substitutions here
server.sendmail(from_addr= me, to_addrs= you, msg=text)
server.quit()
```

**Issue**: Depending on the text sources, the text of my email is either hidden under the image, or all/some of it is underlined/garbled. I'm using gmail and viewing this email in Google Chrome. The original content of the received email can be viewed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L4PcQsKzYaXCMWsRT8QOtnc0VGlfGii-/view?usp=sharing). Can someone point out where I'm incorrect?

Comment: The formatting of an email can be tedious, _depending on the email client in which you read it_.  
Which email client are you using ?  
Can you try and add the generated html : use smthg like 'see source', or 'see original' in you email client to get the generated html ...

Comment: @St3an I edited the "Issue" section with answers to your questions. Let me know if more information would be helpful in better representing the problem. Thanks